# Django - How can view function see difference of the endpoint being hit , without any value stated in the url?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, backend

I'm fairly new to Django and here's my case.

If i have 3 endpoints that i can't modify, and i need to point them to one same View function such as :

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    url(r'^a/', views.functionz.as_view(), name='a'),
    url(r'^b/', views.functionz.as_view(), name='b'),
    url(r'^c/', views.functionz.as_view(), name='c'),
...
]
```

If I'm restricted from changing the endpoints `a/`, `b/`, and `c/` to something else that accepts parameters like `xyz/a` or `xyz/b`, how can my view function `functionz` identify the difference between them when it is being called?

Can I do something like this pseudocode?

***views.py***

```
Class XYZ(API View):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if request.endpoint == '/a/':
        # do things if and only if the client hits /a/
```

Comment: You can use decorator functions and map different urls to such different function-views.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if mapping diffrent url patterns to same view is a good idea, but if you want to do that logic with in the  `post` you probably can use the [`get_full_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_full_path) to get the current path and parse the last the item.

```
Class XYZ(API View):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        current_path = request.get_full_path().rsplit("/", 1)
        if current_path == 'a':
           # Do something
        if current_path == 'b':
           # Do something
```